# Are zero heat exchange and zero work done synonymous to reversibility?

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

Instead of using the definition involving entropy or quasi-static processes, if I am simply able to prove that both work done (on the gas or by the gas, doesn't really matter) and heat exchange through a process are zero, is it sufficient to prove that the process must have been reversible? If so, does it mean that $every$ process with zero heat exchange and work is a reversible one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need only one counterexample to show that the hypothesis is wrong. Here is a counterexample. An insulated vessel is divided into two chambers by a partition. One chamber contains a gas, the other is evacuated. A split occurs in the partition, so that the gas expands into the chamber that used to be evacuated. This is an irreversible change (called 'Joule expansion'). Yet no work is done on or by the system, and no heat flows in or out.

Comment: Another example is that of placing a hot body in contact with a cold body and allowing them to thermally equilibrate.  There is no heat transfer from the surroundings to the two bodies and no work done on the surroundings.  Yet the process is highly irreversible.

Comment: That's a very neat example!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the first law

$$ \Delta U = W + Q. $$

It is simply a restatement of conservation of energy. Thus if you force $W=Q=0$, then your system can have no change in energy, whatsoever. Nor can it make any energy exchange with the environment.

Take the thermodynamic identity,

$$\mathrm{d}U = T \, \mathrm{d}S - P \, \mathrm{d}V + \mu \, \mathrm{d}N.$$

If we conclude that $\mathrm{d}U = 0$, then we can only make comments about the relationships here. In a case where $\mathrm{d}N = 0$, we have

$$ T \, \mathrm{d}S = P \, \mathrm{d}V, $$

so the process is only reversible if there is no change in volume. Any change in volume of the system would constitute work, so we would see that the entropy could never increase if we fix $W_{\rm net} = 0$. So you would say the process is reversible in that case.

Comment: How does no change in internal energy mean that there is no change in entropy? A system can be isolated and still increase in entropy. In fact, there are isolated thermodynamic systems where there is no change in internal energy due to heat or work.

Comment: Just because W=Q=0, the process is **not** non-existent. Take an isobaric process for instance in which temperature is first increased and then decreased back to the original point. Both net heat exchange and work done are zero in the process yet the process _happened_.

Comment: You are both correct. I answered prematurely. I have edited my response. @AaronStevens To my understanding, an isolated system can only increase its entropy through work energy, since it is not exchanging heat or particles.

Comment: I think you have an incorrect notion that energy is required to increase entropy. This is just not the case.